# How to use a value in a listbox in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, listbox

So I have a listbox with values in it. The goal is to click on an item, then populate a separate listbox with matched data. I can handle the match and population for the second listbox, but right now my code doesn't return a value when I select the item in the first listbox. I can see that my value isn't being returned because the code breaks on the line where I set the value of a cell to the "name" variable I'm using:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim iCnt As Long
    Dim name As Variant

    For iCnt = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(iCnt) = True Then
            name = Me.ListBox1.List(iCnt)
            ThisWorksheet.Sheets("Program").Range("K6").Value = name
        End If
        'subsequent match and populate will go here.

End Sub
```

How do I correct my syntax to return the string value of the selected item so I can then use it for my subsequent match?

Comment: Where's your `Next iCnt`?

Comment: [This](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-2/#The_ListBox_Cheat_Sheet) tutorial should get you started.

Comment: Sorry, I chopped it up a bit. I had all my Nexts and End Ifs in there, just had the wrong code. Posted the answer below. Didn't even need a For loop, just the proper command.

Comment: Some hints: 1) `ThisWorksheet.Sheets("Program")….` is incorrect and will raise an error message, should be: `ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("(Program")...` or refer simply to the sheet's `.CodeName`, 2) `.List` requires a 2-dimensional reference including 0-based row plus column index, not only (`ListBox1.List(iCnt)`, 3) you don't need to loop to the entire listbox list to get the actual zero-based `ListBox1.ListIndex`, 4) avoid baptizing a variable `name`, i.e. don't overload existing method or function names you could get into troubles.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = Me.ListBox1.Value
```

This was the correct code